# call other function inside the jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-plugins

I want start to write my own plugin
my problem is calling other function but both of them are in one plguin
how can i call other function inside this function?

and is this code true? ---->

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    }
    $.fn.callHello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            hello();
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

tnx

Comment: Did you try `$.fn.hello()`?

Comment: $.fn.callHello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            $.fn.hello();
        });
    }
this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here hello is another plugin, so you need to call like you call any other plugin using `$(el).plugin()`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    }
    $.fn.callHello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            $(this).hello()
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6WEbS/)

Also there is no need to of the `each` loop

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.hello = function() {
        this.each( function() {
            console.log("Hello", this);
        });
    }
    $.fn.callHello = function() {
        this.hello();
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YFLBw/)